# Retrofit 2 Interface - The Right Way?

Tags: android, optimization, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm <strike>a little</strike> a lot paranoid about writing code the right way. I've used Retrofit in a lot of projects (Android apps) so far.

I usually create a singleton helper class to get instance of retrofit, and a single interface with all API calls.

Something like this:

```
public class RetrofitHelper {
    public static API getInstance() {
        return ourInstance.client;
        // client = retrofit.create(API.class); instantiated only once in singleton constructor
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface API {
    @POST("api/url")
    Observable<ResponseObject> methodOne(@Body RequestBody requestBody);

    @GET("api/url/2")
    Observable<ResponseObject> methodTwo();

    @GET("api/url/3")
    Observable<ResponseObject> methodThree();
}
```

I thought this is fine, but whenever I see code samples people seem to be using separate interface for each/group of API calls and multiple instances of retrofit.

Which is the correct way? Does either of those method affect memory/performance differently?

Can you refer to a project/code sample which uses "the right way" of retrofit? If it's with Retrofit2 + RxJava + MVP Architecture - that'll be perfect!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No one creates Multiple instance that is not the optimized way :

you can refer the below links to sample codes to understand dagger 2 retrofit and MVP :

1. [Hello MVP simple](https://github.com/grandstaish/hello-mvp-dagger-2/blob/master/app/build.gradle)
2. [Aditya Ladwa has explained it easily](https://adityaladwa.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/dagger-2-and-mvp-architecture/)
3. [Here is Medium Article on it](https://android.jlelse.eu/mvp-dagger-2-rx-clean-modern-android-app-code-74f63c9a6f2f)
4. [dagger 2 mvp](https://github.com/fr4nk1/retro-dagger-example)

   `**NOTE** 
   Dagger allows you to create a application scope object and use it throughout app, no need to create new instance everytime`

Edit :

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    @AppScope
    @Provides
    APIInteface providesRetrofitApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(APIInteface.class);
    }

}
```

Once you have the object you can use it anywher using `@Inject APIInterface apiInterface;`

Comment: I need a different header with custom value for each API. So how can I manage API call?

Comment: `@GET("/feeds/flowers.json")
    Observable<List<FlowerResponse>> signUp(@Body SignUpRequest signUpRequest);`

Comment: you have to create different request model and then pass it as @body

Comment: then its Multiple instance of `Retrofit`.

Comment: I dont think so because it is Singleton     `@Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory, RxJava2CallAdapterFactory callAdapterFactory) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(callAdapterFactory)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }`

Comment: if it is @Singleton how can you say it has multiple instance?

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya did you refer the links that I have provided? I request you to first go through them

Comment: `retrofit.create()` method creates a new instance (check its source).

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya does the header value differ for each request or it's same for each request (something like access_token)?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya Please `Note : Above is generic example to explain, yes you can have different headers as per your API`

Comment: @Kalpit I have 4 combinations of the header and each API require any of one the combination.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya here's a quick good tutorial for it: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header & also this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-dynamic-request-headers-with-headermap